# innerHTML and FireFox compatibility?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, innerhtml

I have a javascript function. I use that function to add listboxes in a table row at runtime in the html file. The script runs fine in IE, chrome 22, And FFox 16. But listboxes are not visible when using firefox3 on same machine, where everything is alright on IE.

Please suggest me if any changes needed so this code could run fine on firefox 3 as well

Here's the JavaScript code:

```
function addListBoxes(rowPos)
{

allTables[0].deleteRow(rowPos); //first, delete the row
var row = allTables[0].insertRow(rowPos);  //reinsert the row
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
var cell5=row.insertCell(4);

    cell1.innerHTML="";
    cell2.innerHTML="<select id='relList' name='select' size='5' multiple></select>";
    cell3.innerHTML="";
    cell4.innerHTML="<select id='relSubList' name='select' size='5' multiple></select>";
    cell5.innerHTML="";   
 }
```

UPDATE

On some other threads, I found that document.getElementById is recommended so I updated the script, but it doesn't work either.

```
function addListBoxes(rowPos)
{

    allTables[0].deleteRow(rowPos);
    var row = allTables[0].insertRow(rowPos);
    row.offsetHeight;
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.setAttribute("id", "listRowCell0", 0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.setAttribute("id", "listRowCell1", 0);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.setAttribute("id", "listRowCell2", 0);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.setAttribute("id", "listRowCell3", 0);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    cell5.setAttribute("id", "listRowCell4", 0);

        document.getElementById("listRowCell0").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("listRowCell1").innerHTML="<select id='relList' name='select' size='5' multiple></select>";
        document.getElementById("listRowCell2").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("listRowCell3").innerHTML="<select id='relSubList' name='select' size='5' multiple></select>";  
}
```

Comment: What doctype are you referencing?

Comment: Have you tried it in later firefox versions. I could try it at me but I have also to take some rough allTable and rowpos etc and then my scenario may differ than yours.

Comment: Simple HTML and Javascript. No other scripting language.

Comment: @Sami - the script runs fine in FFox 15 and 16, and I didn't notice any issue. The issue was reported to me by my friend who is using FFox 3, Firefox 3.6.28 on Windows XP to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following at the top of the page, does it work in Firefox 3 then?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks KinKongFrog. I'll try it and will get back to you.